# Conditional replacement of row values

Tags: r

I would like to generate a presence/absence file from a matrix that looks like this by applying some condition

```
source    Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5
  A         0.1       1       2       2       3
  B         1       1       1       1       1
  C         0.2       0       0       1       0
  D         0       0.3       2       0       0
  E         4.4       0.02       0       1       0
  F         1       0       1       0.01       1
  G         0.1       5       0       0       0
```

I want to define low values as being >0.1, so that any value greater than 0.1 gets replaced with a value of 1. The expected results would look like this [values are either 0 or 1]:

```
source    Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5
  A         0       1       1       1       1
  B         1       1       1       1       1
  C         1       0       0       1       0
  D         0       1       1       0       0
  E         1       0       0       1       0
  F         1       0       1       0       1
  G         0       1       0       0       0
```

I would like to do this is R.

Comment: Try with `df1[,-1] <- +(df1[,-1] > 0.1)`  or `df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.integer(x > 0.1))`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You may wish to make your matrix as code so it is easily readable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Also, it helps to give something called an "MCV example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks akrun for your prompt reply, that solved my problem!

Comment: Thanks wwl! I am still a newby! I will take your suggestions in my next post.